# Vue 2 router in beforeEach localStorage is not defined

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Need to do something like middleware,  need to check if the user has a token, then allow the transition

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    const accessNeed = ['Dashboard',]
    if (localStorage.getItem("token")){
        if (!accessNeed.includes(to.name)) {
            next({ name: 'Home' })
        }else{
            next()
        }
    }else{
        next()
    }
})
```

[image]

Comment: Is it `window.localStorage`?

Comment: ReferenceError: window is not defined

Comment: Possibly that's eslint rules - check out ['window' is not defined in Vue.js 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40728493/16791505)

Comment: eslint is not installed

Comment: That's doubtful - did you explicitly remove it?

Comment: no i installed vue without eslint

Comment: Well, `window` is available in the Vue app - unless you are using Nuxt or some other SSR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are either using Nuxt, or just the Vue SSR package. So you have to make sure, the code gets executed only on client:

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (!process.client) {
    next()
    return
  }
    
  const accessNeed = ['Dashboard']

  if (window && window.localStorage.getItem("token")){
    if (!accessNeed.includes(to.name)) {
      next({ name: 'Home' })
    } else{
      next()
    }
  }

  next()
})
```

Comment: I just zoomed the stack, he's using `vue-server-renderer`.

Comment: Probably should be `if (window && window.localStorage.getItem("token")){`

Comment: Right, this should be bulletproof then. I've added it to the answer

Comment: yes i am using Vue SSR, thanks a lot, worked