# VUE + google map how include api google

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js

I started using vue. How can I include Google API to my page? This is my code:

```
<template>
    <div id="map"></div>
</template>

 <script>

export default {
methods: {
  init () {
    var map
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 16,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91722, 151.23064),
      mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    })
  }
}
}

</script>
```

Where can I set

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YourKey&callback=App.map" async defer></script>
```

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44634193/integrating-google-maps-in-vue-js) may help

Answer (score 1):

The script element goes in your index.html file, for example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YourKey&callback=App.map" async defer></script>
</html>
```

If this doesnt work for you, try removing the callback from the end of the `<script>` element's `src` attribute as well as the async and defer keywords, so it looks like:

`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YourKey"></script>`

Then in your vue instance, call your `init()` function once the App component has mounted. See below:

```
export default {
  mounted () {
    this.init()
  },
  methods: {
    init () {
      var map
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 16,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91722, 151.23064),
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: try do like u say...  
 14:19 error 'google' is not defined no-undef

Comment: Im going to assume that your using single file components with a JavaScript linter.

You're getting that error because when the linter checks the single file component it doesnt see 'google' defined anywhere and yet you are referencing it. This is fine because we know its being loaded by index.html

You can supress the error message by adding `/* eslint-disable no-undef */` just above your `export default {` line in your `<script>` section.

Comment: hm... i just start use `global` ty all for the answers

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to put the google map api just before `</body>`. Make sure your vue element is called before google map api (i.e. within app.js). Put `initMap` as the google api's callback.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <map lat="1.23456" lng="100.21345"></map>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script><!-- your vue element should be here -->
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YourKey&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is my code in `Map.vue`, which has a definition of `window.initMap(..)`. I also have a marker (pin) inside the map.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div ref="map" style="width: 100%; height: 200px;"></div>
  </div>
</template>

export default {
  props: [
    'lat', 
    'lng'
  ],
  mounted() {
    window.initMap = () => {

      this.mapElement = new google.maps.Map(this.$refs.map, {
        zoom: 14,
        center: {lat: this.lat, lng: this.lng}
      });

      this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {lat: this.lat, lng: this.lng},
        map: this.mapElement
      });
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      mapElement: null,
      marker: null
    }
  }
}
```