# Using google map in Vue / Laravel

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Trying to implement google map into Vue component. But having a hard time. Actually, there is no error. But no map also :) Okay, what I tried so far down below.

In laravel blade I set my api.

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={{env('GOOGLE_MAPS_API')}}&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Then in Vue component;

```js
data() {
        return {
            mapName: "map",
            //some other codes
        }           
},

mounted() {
        this.fetchEstates();
},
methods: {
        fetchEstates(page = 1) {
            axios.get('/ajax', {
                params: {
                    page
                }}).then((response) => {
                    // console.log(response);
                    this.estates = response.data.data;
                    //some other codes....
                    //some other codes....


},
computed: {

        //some other functions in computed... 
        //

        initMap: function(){
                    var options =
                        {
                            zoom : 6,
                            center : {
                                lat:34.652500,
                                lng:135.506302
                            }
                        };

                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(this.mapName), options);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        icon: 'imgs/marker.png',
                        url: "/pages/estates.id",
                        label: {
                            text: this.estates.price,
                            color: "#fff",
                        },
                        position: {
                            lat: this.estates.lat,
                            lng: this.estates.lng
                        }
                    });
                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                            window.location.href = this.url;
                    });


                }
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
```

and last marker `url` id bind is in controller like this,

```
public function details($id)
{
    $estates = allestates::where('id', $id)->first();

    return view('pages.details', compact('estates'));

}
```

Do I missing something in Vue js? Thank you!

Comment: You're probably using `computed` incorrectly in this case. I guess you want to execute `initMap()` when the component is mounted? If you never reference `initMap` in your template, the computed property will never be evaluated. Plus, you're returning void anyway, which is not what a computed property should to begin with.

Comment: Have you tried the existing package?

Comment: actually, trying to make custom map, @GabMic

Comment: @Terry could you please check it again, I updated the question and the code.

Comment: Check your console log. What does it say?

Comment: when I do the `console.log(this.estates.lat);` inside the initMap function. undefined returns. it looks like I can't pass this.estates into initMap function... or my doing is wrong? what is the correct way to do this? @Terry

Comment: Ah, that's because your async promise has not been resolved (no data returned from endpoint yet), so the `this.estates` is not yet populated. If that's the case, you should move all the marker creation logic from `initMap()` into the `.then()` promise resolution.

Comment: The code you’ve pasted is clearly incorrect. Did you really copy my entire code I’ve posted correctly? `insertMarkers` is not a function inside `initMap`. It is a sibling of that method. Read my answer once again and make sure you copy the code properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From our discussion in the comments, I realise that your issue is because `this.estates` is still not defined when `initMap()` is executed. Remember that you are using an asynchronous operation (via axios) to populate `this.estates`, so it is undefined at runtime. What you can do is:

1. Keep the map initialisation logic in `initMap()`
2. Move all the Google Map marker creation until after the axios promise has been resolved. You can abstract all that into another method, e.g. `insertMarkers()`

Also, remember that you need to define `estates` in the app/component data, otherwise it will not be reactive.

Here is an example:

```
data() {
    return {
        mapName: "map",

        // Create the estate object first, otherwise it will not be reactive
        estates: {}
    }           
},

mounted() {
    this.fetchEstates();
    this.initMap();
},
methods: {
    fetchEstates: function(page = 1) {
        axios.get('/ajax', {
            params: {
                page
            }}).then((response) => {
                this.estates = response.data.data;

                // Once estates have been populated, we can insert markers
                this.insertMarkers();

                //pagination and stuff... 
            });
    },

    // Iniitialize map without creating markers
    initMap: function(){
        var mapOptions =
            {
                zoom : 6,
                center : {
                    lat:34.652500,
                    lng:135.506302
                }
            };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(this.mapName), mapOptions);
    },

    // Helper method to insert markers
    insertMarkers: function() {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            icon: 'imgs/marker.png',
            url: "/pages/estates.id",
            label: {
                text: this.estates.price,
                color: "#fff",
            },
            position: {
                lat: this.estates.lat,
                lng: this.estates.lng
            }
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            window.location.href = this.url;
        });
    }
},
```

---

**Update**: It also turns out that you have not addressed the issue of the data structure of `this.estates`. It appears that you are receiving an array from your endpoint instead of objects, so `this.estates` will return an array, and of course `this.estates.lat` will be undefined.

If you want to iterate through the entire array, you will have to use `this.estates.forEach()` to go through each individual estates while adding the marker, i.e.:

```
data() {
    return {
        mapName: "map",

        // Create the estate object first, otherwise it will not be reactive
        estates: {}
    }           
},

mounted() {
    this.fetchEstates();
    this.initMap();
},
methods: {
    fetchEstates: function(page = 1) {
        axios.get('/ajax', {
            params: {
                page
            }}).then((response) => {
                this.estates = response.data.data;

                // Once estates have been populated, we can insert markers
                this.insertMarkers();

                //pagination and stuff... 
            });
    },

    // Iniitialize map without creating markers
    initMap: function(){
        var mapOptions =
            {
                zoom : 6,
                center : {
                    lat:34.652500,
                    lng:135.506302
                }
            };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(this.mapName), mapOptions);
    },

    // Helper method to insert markers
    insertMarkers: function() {

        // Iterate through each individual estate
        // Each estate will create a new marker
        this.estates.forEach(estate => {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                icon: 'imgs/marker.png',
                url: "/pages/estates.id",
                label: {
                    text: estate.price,
                    color: "#fff",
                },
                position: {
                    lat: estate.lat,
                    lng: estate.lng
                }
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                window.location.href = this.url;
            });
        });
    }
},
```

Comment: okay, I am getting an error that says: `SyntaxError: /var/www/html/laravel/resources/js/components/Index.vue: Unexpected token (222:35)` and it shows the insert function? https://imgur.com/a/3A4At4j

Comment: @Barbie There’s a missing curly bracket when you’re copy and pasting, so `initMap()` is never closed properly. Check again. The code I posted is syntactically correct.

Comment: checked several times, but still catch nothing... I updated full methods in the question, do I really missing anything? :)

Comment: @Barbie Looks at the screenshot you posted again. You’re missing `},` before `insertMarkers: function(){`. I don’t know how much clearer I can get

Comment: oh, really sorry about that, really my mistake/miss. I correct it now. But still getting same error which is `undefined`. Also updated the code in the question.

Comment: This is an excellent lesson in including as much information in your question as needed for troubleshooting. From your original question it was *never* apparent what your data structure is.

Comment: Thank you, you are right about that.  And see you updated the answer. I will check it as answer. Because it might be more helpful for others...

Answer (score -1):

From what I can see in the screenshot you posted, `this.estates` is an array of objects? If that's the case you need to iterate through the array using `forEach`

```js
this.estates.forEach((estate, index) => { 
    console.log(estate.lat); 
    //handle each estate object here
});
```

or use the first item in the array like so `this.estates[0].lat`, if you're only interested in the first item.