# Use Reverse Geocoding in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js, google-maps-api-3, reverse-geocoding

I'm working on a project which track GPS locations and should display in Google map as points. Therefore I use [Reverse Geocoding](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse).

I just put **below code** inside `methods:` in my `Component`.

```
        initMap() {
          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 8,
            center: {lat: 40.731, lng: -73.997}
          });
          var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
          var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

          document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
            this.geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow);
          });
        },
        geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow) {
          var input = document.getElementById('latlng').value;
          var latlngStr = input.split(',', 2);
          var latlng = {lat: parseFloat(latlngStr[0]), lng: parseFloat(latlngStr[1])};
          geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status) {
            if (status === 'OK') {
              if (results[0]) {
                map.setZoom(11);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: latlng,
                  map: map
                });
                infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
              } else {
                alert('No results found');
              }
            } else {
              alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
            }
          });
        }
```

Also I put **below code** in `app.blade.php`

```
    <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
```

My problem is when I use `callback` in parameter the `initMap` function is not identified. Therefore map is not loading on my view. How should I use it? and also should I need to use `axios.get(my_url_here)` to do this? I'm stuck in this case. If anyone can consider and help me for this matter would be grateful.

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44634193/integrating-google-maps-in-vue-js

Comment: Thank you very much @thibautg. I'll try it.