# vue.js is not displaying google maps

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-maps

I am working on a webpage that is supposed to be displaying a google map.  However, I can not get it to display properly.  I have a good API key as I can get the JSON file.  Any advice would be appreciated.

index.html:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=***APIKEY***&callback=initMap"></script>
```

*note I have seen it done with and without the callback.

LocationMap.vue:

```
<template>
    <v-app>
        <div id='ConnectMap'>
            <div ref='map'>
            </div>
        </div>
    </v-app>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: 'Map',
    data() {
        return{
            map:null,
            mapCenter:{lat:37.773972,lng:-122.431297}
        }
    },
mounted(){
this.initMap();
},
    methods:{

            // initMap()
        
        initMap(){
            this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.$refs.map,{
                center: this.mapCenter,
                zoom: true,
                maxZoom: 20,
                minZoom: 3,
                streetViewControl: true,
                mapTypeControl: true,
                fullscreenControl: true,
                zoomControl: true
            })
        
    }
    }
}
</script>
```

currently, as the code is I get an `uncaught in promise` error.  The error states that initMap is not a function.  If I remove the callback I get no error message.  Either way, my map does not display.

**UPDATE** I added a call to initMap inside mounted.  However, this is now giving me a race condition on setzoom.

Comment: Where are you calling `initMap`?

Comment: I was actually missing the call for initMap.  I updated my question, with the call and a new race condition error.

Comment: Thanks for updating, can you please add more information about the race condition error you're seeing?

Comment: What do you mean by "a race condition on setzoom"?

Comment: There are different ways to integrate Google Maps in vue. You can check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44634193/integrating-google-maps-in-vue-js