# JavaScript Error: document is not defined. [no-undef]

Tags: javascript

I am  new to the  Web Development, so i am trying a to learn JavaScript, but i'm always getting this Error.

Code:

```
var myImage = document.querySelector('img');

myImage.onclick = function () {
    var mySrc = myImage.getAttribute('src');
    if (mySrc === 'images/old-big-garage.png') {
      myImage.setAttribute('src', 'images/name1.png');
    } else {
      myImage.setAttribute('src', 'images/old-big-garage.png');
    }
}
```

Errors:

```
JSLint (4)
    4   Missing 'use strict' statement. var mySrc = myImage.getAttribute('src');
    6   Expected 'myImage' at column 9, not column 7.   myImage.setAttribute('src', 'images/papst.png');
    8   Expected 'myImage' at column 9, not column 7.   myImage.setAttribute('src', 'images/old-big-garage.png');
    10  Expected ';' and instead saw '(end)'.   }

ESLint (1)
    1   ERROR: 'document' is not defined. [no-undef]    var myImage = document.querySelector('img');
```

Comment: How exactly are you trying to run that script? Because if you're using node, you're way off base. The above script needs to be included in an HTML document.

Comment: i am using it with an html script in the Brackets io.

Comment: Should i post the html File?

Comment: It looks like you're telling brackets to run/compile this. What you're supposed to do though is open the HTML file in your browser. Which tutorial/resource are you following?

Comment: Are you using some closure?

Comment: I am following this "tutorial":
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics

Comment: you can allow globals, such as document, in the eslint config: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30398825/eslint-window-is-not-defined-how-to-allow-global-variables-in-package-json, but really you shouldn't need to compile your js

Comment: @Noah Ok, so stop whatever you're trying to do and just do step 5. instead. (or save your script in the editor, then hit F5 in the browser to refresh) The process you're using that results in the errors you see is unnecessary for client side JS.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it was really my mistake

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with linter: ESlint.
Try to install bracketeslint: `File ->Extension Manager-> bracketeslint`.
After you are done with it, `Debug -> Reload with Extension ( F5 )`.

You could disable `JSlint` if you want. This way you will not get irritating warnings.

Hope that will work.