# Window is not defined in serviceWorker.js

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I encountered this error when I use eslint. I follow the standard rule of writing code which is recommended by the eslint. With that I also did some work for find the solution recommended by the google pages.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.12.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.15.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.12.4"
}
```

[image: This the error what i got]

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable globals in your `.eslintrc` or wherever you put your eslint configuration.

See [ESLint - "window" is not defined. How to allow global variables in package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30398825/eslint-window-is-not-defined-how-to-allow-global-variables-in-package-json)